# Inner join large database with duplicate values

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I got very large database where I need to find records with timestamp column value older than 30 days but exclude rows where timestamp value within last 30 days. and join it with another table to display. Also please take note that DB storage is based on slow HDD.

```
User table

TIMESTAMP   USER
2022-09-10  BOB
2022-08-20  BOB
2022-08-15  SAL
2022-05-07  MIKE
2022-04-07  RON
2022-03-07  BOB
2022-02-07  SAL
2022-01-15  JAKE
    

Tag Table

USER    TAG
BOB     active
SAL     pending
MIKE    inactive
RON     active
JAKE    pending
```

I want display values from user table  where timestamp value is older than 30 days but exclude the row if it's found within 30 days and join it with  ta table TAG

output should be like this

```
USER    TAG
MIKE    inactive
RON     active
JAKE    pending
```

what I've tried so far.

get the all the rows from USER table where TIMESTAMP within 30 days and save to user_active table

get all the rows from USER table where TIMESTAMP not within last 30 days  and USER not in user_active table and save to user_inactive table

and try to join it as follows

```
SELECT U.USERNAME, U.TIMESTAMP, T.TAG
FROM 
  user_inactive  AS U 
RIGHT JOIN 
  TAG_TABLE AS T
ON
U.USERNAME=T.USERNAME
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: There are no "duplicate values" in that sample.  There _are_ multiple rows for some 'users'.  Is that what you mean?  Further, are we supposed to deduce "active", etc from the rows for each user?  If so, what are the rules.

Comment: yes. first I need to get all the rows where TIMESTAMP old more than 30 days. 
and check the USER of those rows and omit if the same USER found in Less than 30 days. and JOIN it with TAG table  where USER=USER and show USER and TAG

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. [ask] [Help] Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
select u.user,t.tag
from  user_tbl u 
inner join tag_tbl t on u.user=t.user
where  u.user not in ( select user
                         from user_tbl 
                         where `timestamp` >=(now() -INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
                       )  ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/xAYECjwU

The `where  u.user not in` will filter all the users that have the timestamp between current time and 3 months interval.
Alternatively, you could use exists.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. is there any way I can get this output for chunks of 1 month of time ?.  because this  query simply hangs the database as the USER table is extremely large.